# Java Framework for automation based on Pixel Pattern recoginition

Tags: java, image-processing, automation, pattern-matching

I have to develop some kind of bot for a testing background with Java. We used Selenium for all the web stuff, and outside the browser: Pixel recognition; that is, taking a screenshot, then compare it with a image I have already, and get the coordinates of where that pattern is on the screenshot.

Any Framework or free Java libraries that could make this job easier?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: There is a similar question on SO : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4328187/image-comparison-techniques-with-java

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could probably get the following to work:

- Use [java.awt.Robot](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1,5.0/docs/api/java/awt/Robot.html) to take a screen capture as a BufferedImage
- Convert the BufferedImage to a byte array
- Do a standard string matching search to locate the pattern in the byte array. Even a naive string search (i.e. checking for the pattern at every possible location) could well be fast enough.
- Convert the position in the byte array back to image co-ordinates

Answer (score 0):

You could read [this simple example](http://mindmeat.blogspot.com/2008/07/java-image-comparison.html).