# junit approach for creating Icon

Tags: java, junit

I have a method

Icon getMoleculeIcon(Molecule mol)

which I want to test. What is the right way to do this? I was thinking about checking whether return is Icon.class or maybe something with comparing hashCodes.
The latter seems better to me but I am really not sure.
Thanks for any help.

Comment: Try http://en.kioskea.net/faq/5588-mokito-framework

Comment: What would you need to test for to see if the result was right?

Comment: @Thorbjørn Ravn Andersen That was my question :) I wanted somehow see if the binaries of mock and test are the same (I am creating this Icon on fly so it is good to know for me)

Comment: You want to test it.  What do you want to test it _for_?

Answer (score 2):

Your result must be well determinate if you pass molecule mol you need to have stored in one file or in a class the Icon corresponding object.

Icon is javax.swing  Interface Icon?

If so you have to derminate if the returned type could be ImageIcon.

When you have an ImageIcon you can getImage();

When you have Image object you can play with It using PixelGrabber class

http://www.java-tips.org/java-se-tips/java.awt.image/how-to-use-pixelgrabber-class-to-acquire-pixel-data-from-an-image-o.html

---

Another interesting conversion is the use of BufferedImage http://www.java.net/node/646586

---

Now when you understand that in Java there are too many class to work with image, and you have an array of pixel of both image (generated by your code passing determinated param, and the one stored in your class or loaded by a file that is the deterministic result of passing the specific param).

You are ready to compare the image. Pixel by Pixel or with a brain intensive method.

---

Another solution is to create your object with Icon interface and define your comparison method

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/Comparable.html

---

There are other interesting suggestion:

[Image Comparison Techniques with Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4328187/image-comparison-techniques-with-java)

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6971966/how-to-measure-percentage-similarity-between-two-images

someone has done some great lib

http://mindmeat.blogspot.it/2008/07/java-image-comparison.html

---

This is a real complex check to do, but it is really important on some product. I don't know if is your case and if you have enough time to spend on this task.

I hope to be useful.

Comment: Thank you for such a comprehensive answer. Exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: @LtWorf1 I would love to but my reputation is too low to allow me to do that. I could only marked his answer as useful.