# how to compare set of images in java using pixel based image comparision metric based on mean squared error?

Tags: java, image-processing

In my project i have a set of images. I need to compare them. Each pixel from one image is compared to the pixel at the same location in all other images in the dataset. After applying mean squared error calculation to all of the pixels in image space, a set of different pixels are identified which represents pixels with varying color values in the images. 
I have compared and stored similarities pixels in a file for two images.but can't do this for 12 images.'code'

```
import java.io.*;
import java.awt.*;
import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
class spe
{
    public static void main(String args[]) 
    throws IOException
    {
        long start = System.currentTimeMillis();
        int q=0;
            File file1 = new File("filename.txt");

        /* if file doesnt exists, then create it
        if (!file.exists()) {
                    file.createNewFile();
                }*/
        FileWriter fw = new FileWriter(file1.getAbsoluteFile());
        BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(fw);

                File file= new File("2000.png");
            BufferedImage image = ImageIO.read(file);
        int width = image.getWidth(null);
            int height = image.getHeight(null);
        int[][] clr=  new int[width][height]; 
        File files= new File("2002.png");
            BufferedImage images = ImageIO.read(files);
        int widthe = images.getWidth(null);
            int heighte = images.getHeight(null);
        int[][] clre=  new int[widthe][heighte]; 
        int smw=0;
        int smh=0;
        int p=0;
            //CALUCLATING THE SMALLEST VALUE AMONG WIDTH AND HEIGHT
            if(width>widthe)
            { 
                smw =widthe;
            }
            else 
            {
                smw=width;
            }
            if(height>heighte)
            {
                smh=heighte;
            }
            else 
            {
                smh=height;
            }
            //CHECKING NUMBER OF PIXELS SIMILARITY
            for(int a=0;a<smw;a++)
            {
                for(int b=0;b<smh;b++)
                {
                    clre[a][b]=images.getRGB(a,b);
                    clr[a][b]=image.getRGB(a,b);
                    if(clr[a][b]==clre[a][b]) 
                    {
                        p=p+1;
                        bw.write("\t");
                         bw.write(Integer.toString(a));
                        bw.write("\t");
                         bw.write(Integer.toString(b)); 
                        bw.write("\n");
                    }
                    else
                        q=q+1;
                }
            }

    float w,h=0;
    if(width>widthe) 
    {
        w=width;
    }
    else 
    {
        w=widthe;
    }
    if(height>heighte)
    { 
        h = height;
    }
    else
    {
        h = heighte;
    }
    float s = (smw*smh);
    //CALUCLATING PERCENTAGE
    float x =(100*p)/s;

    System.out.println("THE PERCENTAGE SIMILARITY IS APPROXIMATELY ="+x+"%");
    long stop = System.currentTimeMillis();
    System.out.println("TIME TAKEN IS ="+(stop-start));
    System.out.println("NO OF PIXEL GETS VARIED:="+q);
    System.out.println("NO OF PIXEL GETS MATCHED:="+p);
  }
}
```

Comment: please put what you have done so far??

Comment: i have got png images as input from url.

Comment: but for comparing have you wrote any sort of code?? if so then please put it here

Answer (score 1):

Right now your code will compare always the file 2000.png with 2002.png. 
First refactor your comparison code into a method:

```
CompareResult compare(BufferedImage  img1,BufferedImage  img2) { ... }
```

Declare a class CompareResult to group the result info into one Message:

```
class CompareResult {
     long pixMatched;
     long pixVar;
     ...
}
```

Then expect a list of image files from commandline and compre them each to each other:

```
for(int i=0;i<args.length();i++) {
    BufferedImage img1 = ImageIO.read(args[i]);
    for (int j=i+1;j<args.length();j++) {
        BufferedImage img2 = ImageIO.read(args[j]);
        CompareResult r = compare(img1,img2);
        printInfo(r);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
  File file1 = new File(args[0]);
  File file2 = new File(args[1]);

  boolean compareResult = FileUtils.contentEquals(file1, file2);
  System.out.println("Are the files are same? " + compareResult);
```

**Apache Commons IO library to perform this comparison** (download commons-io-2.4.jar)

Comment: This might not work if the pixels are a distance from each other. When accessing the actual pixels, you can calculate the color distance from pixel to another and use an acceptance threshold for matching the two. So like, a lighter shade of red versus a darker shade of red. Both colors will have the RED channel greater than GREEN and BLUE.