# Compare two different images using selenium Webdriver 2

Tags: selenium, automation, webdriver

Apart from the built-in methods, how can I two different images using selenium Webdriver 2?

Image format is jpg. In about us WebPage we have multiple images. I want compare those images.

Comment: Are the images hosted somewhere?

Comment: I think you can compare images name rather than images..

Comment: Please add more details like `image formats` -are both in same or different- and a bit about your mention of difference between to image -Dimension is important or not- and so on ;).

Comment: Image format is jpg. In an application we have multiple images in about us Web page.  I want compare those images. Thanks, In Advance

Comment: What do you want to compare? FileSize? Image size (width or height)? Or the content of the images?

Comment: I Want to compare the image pixel by pixel and also file size.

Comment: Which programming language? If java, then see these - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21179019/how-to-compare-set-of-images-in-java-using-pixel-based-image-comparision-metric, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8567905/how-to-compare-images-for-similarity-using-java

Answer (score -1):

You can include sikuli in your webdriver script and can match the images.

Comment: Please post the source code and the way to achieve it. Thanks