# How to recognize image which template is stored in the app

Tags: android, image, image-processing

It needs recognize icons. For example, the app scans with with phone **camera** and recognizes one of the icons below and if it recognized then the app performs some action. It recognizes it by comparing with icons stored in the app.

Any libs, manuals, please.

And how to name this task if to search it: optical image recognition? (This is not OCR because recognizing image, not text, right?)

Thank you very much!

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[how to compare set of images in java using pixel based image comparision metric based on mean squared error?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21179019/how-to-compare-set-of-images-in-java-using-pixel-based-image-comparision-metric)

[Image Comparison Techniques with Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4328187/image-comparison-techniques-with-java)

[Java library to compare image similarity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8644960/java-library-to-compare-image-similarity)

Google "java code to compare two images"

Also you can try perform and compare MD5 of both images, but i can't guarantee it will work(depends on your situation and if the files are the same).